# Use function to get template value

Tags: angularjs, pug

I would like to send my Jade javascript render functions to the browser and have an angular directive render the result of the function instead of static html. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

This expert programmer appears to have done something comparable.

http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/